# NonlinearModelFit error: nrlnum

Tags: fitting, warning-messages

I use `NonlinearModelFit`:

```
data = 
  {{1804, 1}, {1850, 1.26}, {1927, 2.0}, {1960, 3.0}, 
   {1974, 4}, {1987, 5}, {1999, 6}, {2011, 7}}
nlm = 
  NonlinearModelFit[data, a*exp[a*t]/(b*(exp[a*t] - 1) + a), {a, b}, t]
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I get the message:

> NonlinearModelFit::nrlnum: The function value {-1.+(1. exp[1804.])/(1. +1. (-1. + exp[<<1>>])), -1.26 + (1. exp[1850.])/(1. + 1. (-1. + exp[<<1>>])), -2. + (1. exp[1927.])/(1. + 1. (<<1>>)), -3. + <<1>>, <<1>>, -5. + <<1>>/<<1>>, -6. + (1. exp[1999.])/(1. + 1. (-1. + exp[<<1>>])), -7. + (1. exp[2011.])/(1. + 1. (-1. + exp[<<1>>]))} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {8} at {a, b} = {1. ,1.}.

So it seems there are some complex values. But I don't understant how they could appear. (I don't use square root function, but only exp). How can I fix this?

Comment: Use `Exp`, not `exp`. MMA is case-sensitive